# Access viewcontext from httpcontext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewdata

I want to get ViewData value from httpcontext. 
My function:

```
[LogActionFilter]
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
{
    var obj = getObjFromDb(id);
    ViewData["abc"] = obj.name;
    return View(obj);
}
```

My action filter where I want to to access `ViewData` value:

```
public class LogActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var a= filterContext.HttpContext.Items["abc"]; //null
        var b = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Items["abc"]; //null
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var a= filterContext.HttpContext.Items["abc"]; //null
        var b = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Items["abc"]; //null
    }
}
```

How can I access the value of `ViewData` from `HttpContext`?

Comment: `ViewData` is for passing data from a controller method to a view. What is it that your trying to do?

Comment: I want to perform some additional checks in LogActionFilter on the basis of data in ViewData

Comment: Sorry, but that is not making sense. For a start you setting the value in the method itself

Comment: @StephenMuecke please see updated question, viewdata value is being set from database.

Comment: Yes, but you still setting the value within the method itself. And its not available in `HttpContext` anyway (its purpose to to pass data from the controller method to the view). You could always make the database call inside the `OnActionExecuting()` method, but its not clear what the purpose of that value is and what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Stephen Muecke,

> `ViewData` is not available in `HttpContext`

So I changed my logic, instead of getting `viewdata` value, I fetched data from database in action filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session to pass value into your OnActionExecuted filter. However you can't pass anything from your action to OnActionExecution because its executed before your action.

```
 [LogActionFilter]
  public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
  {
    var obj = getObjFromDb(id);
    Session["abc"] = obj.name;
    return View(obj);
  }
```

In filter:

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var a = filterContext.HttpContext.Session["abc"];
        /// a should have a value
    }
```